# Annual Donor Report

Tags: civireport, custom-reports, donations

I would like to setup a report where I can see each donor's total donations by year, where each column would be a different year and the corresponding total, and each row would be each donor. Please help !

Answer (score 6):

This type of report is called a "pivot table".  There's a report that will do what you want in the [Extended Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) extension.  If you don't have that installed, do the following (or ask your administrator):

- Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.
- Click the **Add New** tab.
- Search for *Extended Reports* in the extension list and click the corresponding **Download** link.

Note that if your CiviCRM is out of date, you may not see this extension, or you may get an older version that doesn't have this report.

Once the extension is downloaded:

- Go to **Reports menu » Contribution Reports**.
- Click the **New Contribution Report** buton.
- Click the **Extended Report - Contribution Pivot Chart** link.
- In the **Select Row Fields** drop-down, choose **Contact Name**.
- In the **Select Column Header** drop-down, choose **Breakdown by Year**.
- Press **View Results**.

That should give you what you're looking for - see an example below (this is a demo site without much data, yours will most likely look better).  You can save this report in the **Actions** drop-down.

[image]